# Why will only one axis of the Xbox 360 controller work when I've coded for both? (VB.Net)

Tags: vb.net, xna, joystick, gamepad

First of all I'd like to point out I'm an extreme novice, and I fear I may be in over my head here. My issue lies within trying to make the left joystick of the Xbox 360 controller control separate functions on each axis. Currently I am trying to code the controller so it will control a Phidget Motor Controller's outputs with variable speed. I've managed to build my code so that the Y-Axis will control the forward velocity without any issue, but if I try to code the X-Axis separately, to move the motors in a different way, it doesn't work. There are no errors, it just doesn't send to the Phidget.

I've discovered that I can make the X-Axis work like I want to, but only when I remove the code for the Y-Axis. It seems if ones there, the other doesn't want to, as if it's only registering one axis at once. Aside from that, I've found it to work fine and there's no issues. I should also mention that I have a few labels that display the current position of both sticks and they work flawlessly, without a hitch. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
Imports Microsoft.Xna.Framework
Imports Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input
Public Class Form1
Dim WithEvents MC1 As Phidget21COM.PhidgetMotorControl

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MC1 = New Phidget21COM.PhidgetMotorControl
    MC1.Open(15100)
    MC1.WaitForAttachment(3000)

    If MC1.IsAttached = True Then
        PhidStat.Text = "Phidget Attached!"
    Else
        PhidStat.Text = "No Phidget Found"
    End If

    JoyConnect.Text = ""
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    If GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).IsConnected = True Then
        JoyConnect.Text = "Controller Connected!"
    Else
        JoyConnect.Text = "Not Connected. :("
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Controller()
    Dim LX As String
    Dim RX As String
    Dim LY As String
    Dim RY As String

    'Left Joystick
    LX = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Left.X * 100 'Negetive value = Left, Positive = Right
    LX1.Text = LX
    If LX < 0 Then
        MC1.Velocity(0) = LX
        MC1.Velocity(1) = -1 * LX
    End If
    If LX > 0 Then
        MC1.Velocity(0) = LX
        MC1.Velocity(0) = -1 * LX
    End If

    LY = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Left.Y * 100
    LY1.Text = LY
    MC1.Velocity(0) = LX
    MC1.Velocity(1) = LX

    'Right Joystick
    RX = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.X * 100
    RX1.Text = RX

    RY = GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).ThumbSticks.Right.Y * 100
    RY1.Text = RY

End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Controller()
End Sub
End Class
```

One more thing. The motor controller is meant to control to motors for flying an ROV. When the left stick is moved left (Negetive value), motor 0 is to move in reverse, and 1 is to move forward to do a sort of 'point turn', and vice versa for moving the left stick to the right. Furthermore, the y axis controls both at once, either forward or reverse.

Comment: Me again. After much toying around it seems I've found out how to make it run properly, but I am still unsure if this is at all an efficient way to work this type of setup. Right now I have everything coded using a single if statement with multple elseif statements for each direction. It appears to be okay but I'd still like to find a better way.

Comment: If you have a working solution, but want tips for improving you need to edit your question and include the CURRENT code you have